# need help making sense of 後半の二話

Tags: parsing

So, I'm reading this: http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E5%86%A8%E6%A8%AB%E3%81%AF%E4%BA%8C%E5%BA%A6%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8F

And he says this:

> 背景も人物もなぐり描きです。 読み切りのツーショット。鴉ＶＳ蔵馬。幽助ＶＳ仙水。幽助と雷禅が対面する回はほとんど一人で描きました。
>   後半の２話はあるハガキの批判の通り、落ちる寸前の半日で19枚上げたものです。

Is "後半の２話" supposed to refer to the latter two chapters he has named? It would make sense that way, but I feel like I've never seen 後半 used in this particular way before.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you list more than two things (A, B, C, D, and E) and want refer to the *last two* (D and E), the normal wordings are 最後(の)2つ, 後ろ(の)2つ, and 後二者【こうにしゃ】 (formal). 後半(の)2つ would be also OK when there are exactly 4 things in the list.

In this case, I'm having trouble understanding what 後半の2話 refers to. It may be "幽助VS仙水" and "幽助と雷禅が対面する回", but it doesn't seem to match the remainder of the sentence.